# Replace tab with a space inside a String

Tags: java

I can't find a solution to this very simple problem:
I would like to replace a tab in a String with a whitespace (and only one space).
For example, I have a String like this:

```
        Hello        World!        
New line"
```

And I would like to get this as a result:

```
Hello World! 
New line
```

For this, I used this function :
`myStr.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");`

The tabs are well removed... But also the carriage return:
`Hello World! New line`

I also tried to use replaceAll with "[\\t ]" as replacement characters but if I replace with a whitespace, it does not change anything..

I must be missing a simple solution but I don't see...

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the following to match multiple contiguous tabs and spaces.

```
[\\t ]+
```

For regular expressions it's always a good idea to test them out using a tool like https://regexr.com/

There you can enter your sample and the regular expression and it even explains what's going on.

Comment: Quite simply. I feel like an idiot for not having thought of it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

[Whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character):

> is any character or series of characters that represent **horizontal or vertical** space in typography. When

### Issue

In you example the `\s` matched and replaced all of the following:

- regular space like   (horizontal)
- tab like `\t` (horizontal)
- carriage-return like `\r` (vertical)
- new-line or line-feed like `\n` (vertical)

See this [substitution demo](https://regex101.com/r/pEw85v/1) for Java's regex-flavor.

### Alternative Solutions

In Java you could easily condense this horizontal whitespace with:

#### (1) Split by lines and clean each line separately

See the [demo on IdeOne](https://ideone.com/8XHpGO):

```java
String multiLineText = "\tHello        World!" + "\n"        
  + "New line";

String lineSeparatorRegex = "\r?\n"; // usually "\n" on Linux/Mac or "\r\n" on Windows

List<String> condensedLines = new ArrayList();
String[] lines = multiLineText.split(System.lineSeparator()); // alternative: use the regex 
for (String line : lines) {
  condensedLines.add(line.replaceAll("\\s+", " ")); // condense
}
String condensedPerLine = String.join(System.lineSeparator(), condensedLines);
```

Note: `System.getProperty("line.separator")` is the old way before [`System.lineSeparator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator--) was introduced in Java 1.7

#### (2) Simple multi-line capable regex

as [answered by Niko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72565615/5730279):

```
// remove all tabs or additional space characters 
String condensedPerLine = multiLineText.replaceAll("[\t ]+", " ");
```

See on Regex101: [demo preserving lines](https://regex101.com/r/JdP1bj/1).

#### (3) Use Apache StringUtils with streaming:

`StringUtils` class is perfect for handling Strings null-safe, for this case [`normalizeWhitespace(s)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#normalizeSpace-java.lang.String-).
Note there in JavaDocs also the hint:

> Java's regexp pattern \s defines whitespace as [ \t\n\x0B\f\r]

```
// clean all superfluous whitespace and control-characters from lines
String condensedPerLine = Arrays.stream(multiLineText.split(System.lineSeparator())
    .map( s -> return StringUtils.normalizeWhitespace(s))
    .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSepartor()));
```

#### See also

- [Java Multi-line String | Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-multiline-string)
- [Split a String in Java | Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-split-string)
- [Split String between lines with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50131679/split-string-between-lines-with-regex)
- [Difference between \n and System.lineSeparator();?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49340617/difference-between-n-and-system-lineseparator)
- [How to split a String into a Stream of Strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40932813/how-to-split-a-string-into-a-stream-of-strings)
- [Match multiline text using regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651725/match-multiline-text-using-regular-expression)